# React Native fails to import files from folder above project folder

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

React noob here.

I started with react and was able to do the basic. When I wanted to make my code structured for future use, I failed.

I have my project folder, and parallel to it I have a folder for all my common

```
| code:\
|- Code Folder\
|-- Project\
|--- App.js\
|--- screens\
|---- HomeScreen.js\
|-- CommonLibrary\
|--- COLORS.js\
```

COLORS is suppose to contain all the defines for common used colors:

```
export default {
    COLOR_BLACK: "#000000",
    COLOR_DARKBLUE: "#0F3274",
    COLOR_DARKGRAY: "#999",
    COLOR_LIGHTBLUE: "#6EA8DA",
    COLOR_ORANGE: "#C50",
    COLOR_TEXT_LIGHTBLUE: "#159EEA",
    COLOR_WHITE: "#FFFFFF",
};
```

Regardless of what I do, I cannot import the COLORS from HomeScreen. I tried:

```
import COLORS from "../../CommonLibrary/COLORS"
import COLORS from "../../CommonLibrary/COLORS.js"
import {COLORS} from "../../CommonLibrary/COLORS"
import {COLORS} from "../../CommonLibrary/COLORS.js"
```

I tried nohoist, using index.js in the CommonLibrary folder (but I think I did that wrong).
This file is just one example of what I want to do. I also want to make files for commonly used components like custom buttons and things, but those can be after the colors work.

I have googled to the best of my abilities and tried what I can decipher from online but nothing has worked.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do `export const colors = {}` instead and then in other file do `import { colors }` from whatever the path is

Answer (score 0):

Inside COLORS.js it should be

```
export const colors = {
    COLOR_BLACK: "#000000",
    COLOR_DARKBLUE: "#0F3274",
    COLOR_DARKGRAY: "#999",
    COLOR_LIGHTBLUE: "#6EA8DA",
    COLOR_ORANGE: "#C50",
    COLOR_TEXT_LIGHTBLUE: "#159EEA",
    COLOR_WHITE: "#FFFFFF",
};
```

Then in your HomeScreen import it like below:

```
import {colors} from "../../CommonLibrary/COLORS"
```

Answer (score 0):

COLORS.js should be inside project folder

import COLORS from "../COLORS"
should work

Comment: That works but it's not what I wanted. If I have multiple projects, I want to be able to have all the projects use the common code without needing to copy the common files to each project folder. 
If I have 3 projects and all 3 use a specific common file, I will need to copy the common file to each of the projects. In addition, if I need to make a change to one of the common files, I'll need to make the change 3 times and can possibly forget to do some of them

Comment: react native wont let you go beyond the scope of your project, which makes sense to me, you have to put the files inside project